# check if a file is saved with vba

Tags: vba, powerpoint, savefiledialog

I want to give the possibility to save a [powerpoint](/questions/tagged/powerpoint) presentation when my macro executes.

I don't want it to be mandatory so I will insert a pop up asking if they want to save it.

But one problem that I see is that if it is already saved, I don't want anything to appear - how can I check if it is saved or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Presentation.Saved property tells you whether there have been any changes since the last save, and therefore whether you need to save it. Check this property before you show your pop-up.

[Presntation.Saved](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff744884.aspx) on MSDN.